# If $b \equiv 0 \pmod a$ and $c \equiv 0 \pmod b$, then $c \equiv 0 \pmod a$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, modular-arithmetic

The question is If $b \equiv 0 \pmod a$ and $c \equiv 0 \pmod b$, then $c \equiv 0 \pmod a$.

My attempt is that $b \equiv 0 \pmod a$ can be written $a\mid b-0 = a\mid b$
and the same with $c \equiv 0 \pmod b$ can be written $b\mid c-0 = b\mid c$
then the $c \equiv 0 \pmod a$ can also be written $a\mid c-0 = a\mid c$.

Now all I have to show is that $a\mid b$ and $b\mid c$ then $a\mid c$ and to show $a\mid c$ I can write
$c= ak$ for some integer $k$.

Now I start my proof 
let $a\mid b$ be $b=a\cdot r$ for some integer $r$ (1)
let $b\mid c$ be $c=b\cdot s$ for some integer $s$ (2)

Sub (1) into (2) and get
$c=(ar)\cdot s$
$c=a\cdot(r\cdot s)$
so $c=a\cdot k$
therefore the statement $b \equiv 0 \pmod a$ and $c \equiv 0 \pmod b$, then $c \equiv 0 \pmod a$ is true.

I'm wondering if this is a good/correct proof?
any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You did not define what $k$ is, so no, your proof is not correct. You simply state

> So $c=ak$.

What is $k$? How did you prove that $c=ak$?

Comment: @Ganymede The OP asked "is this proof correct?". I answered him (the answer is *no*) and explained to him where the answer is wrong. This should motivate him to improve his answer. On the other hand, you actually wrote a mathematically false thing in your answer, thus I downvoted it. Now you fixed your answer and I removed the downvote. I don't see why you should downvote my answer.

Comment: He did define what $k$ is. It is the integer for which $c=ak$. That comes directly from the definition of $a\mid c$.

Comment: @celtschk If I have a proof in which I want to prove the statement: "there exists such a $k$ that $c=ak$", and I say "let $k$ be the number such that $c=ak$", then the proof is incorrect. You cannot assume that the thing you are trying to prove exists.

Comment: @celtschk The proof is almost entirely correct, but is missing one crucial line: "then, if we set $k$ to be $k=*$, we can see that $c=ak$". Without that line (with *something* written in place of the asterix), the proof is incorrect.

Comment: He *rewrites* the statement "$a\mid c$" he wants to prove into "$c=ak$ for some $k$". That's nothing but another way to state the same. The statement "$c=ak$ for some $k$" is the statement he's going to proof. Note that he writes "**Now** I **start** my proof" *below* that line, so that line is not even part of the proof, so how can it make the proof wrong?

Comment: He writes "$c=a\cdot(r\cdot s)$ so $c=ak$. That makes it absolutely clear that $k=r\cdot s$.

Comment: @celtschk I disagree. It is at very best bad form. And the question is so beginner level that such bad form should be discouraged.

Comment: Bad form $\ne$ incorrect proof. I'm all for discouraging bad form by calling it bad form. I'm all against discouraging bad form by incorrectly claiming it to be incorrect.